# insert apostrophe in String.format, C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I have this `string.format` issue. I'm trying to put a `'` inside of the string.

This is what I have so Far.

```
string.Format(@"SELECT UserID FROM intListAccess IA
JOIN database.[fnc_CommaListDelimeter_to_tableInt](\'{0}\':, N',') I ON i.ID = IA.IntList
WHERE IA.DateTimeStamp >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AND IA.UserID = {1} AND IA.AppId = {2}", 
string.Join(",", IntList), UserID, AppId);
```

What the `fnc_CommaListDelimeter` does is take a string with ints seperated by a comma delemiter like `'122344,524572,126344,847858'` and turns it into a table like

```
|  id  |
|122344|
|524572|
|126344|
|847858|
```

Every time I run the code it sends the function above but doesn't put single quotes around the list being passed to `fnc_CommaListDelimeter`

I tried then putting `\'` around it so it looks like this `\'{0}\'` but then vstudio throws exception saying sqlException invalid syntax near `'122344,524572,126344,847858\'` So when I remove the trailing `\` It throws same error but without the trailing `\`. Is there a way to do this in vstudio using String.Format?

Comment: Evil, evil, evil. String templating to build SQL statements will leave you highly susceptible to SQL Injection attacks. Use parameterized queries. Really. Right now.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve here? Maybe we could help with that instead? It seems to me like you might be interested in [table-valued parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: want to pass something that looks like this `'3333,35535,3535'` to the `fnc_CommaListDelimeter_to_tableInt` but don't now how using string.format

Comment: But why do you need to pass anything to  `fnc_CommaListDelimeter_to_tableInt`? Because you need to pass in a list of values for a query? Use table-valued parameters for that.

Comment: If this a properly parameterized query it would be a non-issue. Of course in my system I would look into that function as string splitters are notoriously poorly written using cursors and/or while loops. If at all possible using a table valued parameter would be a better way than a delimited string.

Comment: @spender. yes I need to pass in a list.

Comment: @ Sean_Lange I didn't write the function and only have that to work with.

Comment: @AbdullahiFarah Then TVPs are perfect for your needs. With TVPs you won't need that function.

Comment: I hope you work at Bill Gates's bank.  I got a little something something to try tonight!

Comment: This is for unit testing everyone. The actual work in production is done on a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I want to start by saying you are doing this the wrong way.  You should be using a stored procedure to access your database from your application layer.  Or at the very least a parameterized query.  Your current implementation is inflexible and leaves you vulnerable to several security problems.  You should absolutely take the advice given to you in the comments.

With that being said, it appears you have an unneeded semi-colon in your code that is causing the problems and the backslashes are not needed when you are using the string literal syntax.  Try this:

```
string.Format(@"SELECT UserID FROM intListAccess IA
JOIN database.[fnc_CommaListDelimeter_to_tableInt]('{0}', N',') I ON i.ID = IA.IntList
WHERE IA.DateTimeStamp >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AND IA.UserID = {1} AND IA.AppId = {2}", 
string.Join(",", IntList), UserID, AppId);
```

Comment: This is for unit testing, don't plan on doing this in the actual web application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer